# Firebase, url with variables redirects to main page

Tags: firebase, redirect, progressive-web-apps, firebase-hosting

I have a link that looks like this:

> https://mywebsite.com/#/new-account?jk=-LOLgLiyfxANW-ojMKrf

jk is the variable that I would like to read and use on this page. The variable will change for each user.

The problem is that when this link is clicked, the user is redirected to the main page of the application. The app is a PWA developed using Ionic. I checked my code carefully and there is nothing that would cause such redirect behavior.

So far I tried uploading the app again with deselecting "single page" option during Firebase Init but the problem persists.

thanks

Comment: That hashtag has meaning and should not be there like that. Why is that `#` there?

Comment: The hashtag is included in the link that Ionic creates for each page in a PWA. Links to other pages with hashtags work because Firebase recognizes them as valid links but when I add a variable to the link, Firebase sees it as an unrecognized page and redirects to main page.

Comment: @kwanite Can you show newAccountPage code ?

Comment: The code parses variables and displays some of the variables on the screen. It works fine now. You may see the answer I posted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I contacted firebase support and they suggested I solve it by including this in firebase.json within the hosting tag:

```
"redirects": [{
"source": "/#/new-account?:vars*",
"destination": "https://mywebsite.com/#/new-account?:vars*",
"type": 301
}]
```

Firebase hosting captures whatever text is after : and transfers it to the destination. Otherwise, it creates a 404 for any link that doesn't exactly match the URL of existing pages.

Maybe there is a more elegant way to do this but it worked well for my situation. More info is available at this link:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#redirects